# Carry dumbbells while running

Tags: running, strength, resistance

Recently I have been training hard for my marathons and I feel that it may not be enough to become a champion.

So I came up with the idea of carrying weight while running.
I have got 2 dumbbells each weighing just 4 lbs. Can I carry these on my hand and swing my arms normally, the way in which I do while jogging?
Will this improve my strength and/or my speed?

Also please tell me, what is the extent of weight that I can carry, if at all this idea is good?

Comment: I don't think I have asked too many questions in one question. Please let me know if I have.

Comment: Hmmmm I used to do that. It's pretty hard. :D So 4 pounds will be just right. You can't swing that normally. Will this improve your strength? Dunno, but it's fun, I liked it.